# Is Mule HTTP connector free?

Tags: mule

can someone pls advise if Mule HTTP connector (and other "Select" connectors) are free? I.e. could be used with Mule CE runtime without necessity of getting MuleSoft subscription?
I've noticed that on the MuleSoft page [here](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/http-integration-connector?searchTerm=http&filters=Select&sortBy=rank) the HTTP connector is described with level "Select".
The description of the connectors with the level "Select" [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/anypoint-connectors) states the following:

> MuleSoft maintains the Select connectors; **you must have an active
>   CloudHub Select plan or an Enterprise subscription with an entitlement
>   for the specific connector you wish to use**.

So, does it mean that the HTTP connector can't be used "for free"?
Is there a "free" alternative if so?

Update: Pls note, that for the connectors that could be used without the paid subscription MuleSoft has a special category "Community" with the following clear statement regarding the use of the connectors:

> **You do not need any special account or license to use a Community
>   connector.**

But the HTTP connector is not in that category.

Update 2: MuleSoft is raising an internal issue with their documentation. Waiting for the update.

Update 3: MuleSoft has updated their web site with the following clarification for the terms of use for the "Select"-category connectors:

> **Connectors included in the open source Mule distribution can be used
>   by everyone, although support is only included in an Anypoint Platform
>   subscription. For all other Select Connectors, you must have an active
>   Anypoint Platform subscription to use them and access support.**

However, unlike for the Community Connectors, it doesn't clarify the terms of the use. Can it be used in Prod? Can it be used for commercial purposes? It's not clear why MuleSoft is using two different statements for "free" connectors: One is for Community and another one for Select catrgory connectors. .

Comment: I believe HTTP should be part of CE. If you could run it on CE runtime then that should confirm it.

Comment: Well, I've expected so. But the MuleSoft website apparently says the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP connector is free to use. Being in the "Select" level means that if any problem is encountered in the connector and you are a customer, MuleSoft Customer Support will help you troubleshoot it.

> This includes configuration assistance, connector updates, patch fixes
>   for critical issues, and enhancements via scheduled release cycles.

Comment: Well, this is very flexible interpretation of the term "use". Once again, here is what the MuleSoft web site says: "you must have an active CloudHub Select plan or an Enterprise subscription with an entitlement for the specific connector you wish to use. "

Answer (score 0):

As Shoki said it is true that MuleSoft will help you to solve issues on Subscription . Also when you deploy the application on Cloud hub then there applies some license over the connector which is also applicable with the meaning of providing "Select:

Comment: I don't have an issue with getting the subscription. I've just noticed that using HTTP connector requires a paid subscription according to the official  MuleSoft web site (I've provided the links in the question). That means that using the connector without the subscription is illegal. Possibly, this is just a documentation mistake on the MuleSoft web site. However, possibly, it's not a mistake. After all, it's all MueSoft copyright code and they decide what license is required.

Comment: If you see the Anypoint studio all the connectors or components that are community are in dark blue and the enterprise or the subscription one will be light blue in color. I hope the link you shared has some restriction and license implication while choosing  the Cloud Hub as your deployment environment

Comment: Ok, look, this question is about licensing. So, if it's  written somewhere on the MuleSoft license agreement that the dark blue colour means you can use it without the subscription then pls point me to such the doc. This is what I'm asking for. So far I've found only a quite clear statement on the official MuleSoft web site that you must have a subscription to use the connector. It says nothing about the colours.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has been updated, the Level of the Connector is still Select because it means that is fully maintained and supported by Mulesoft, but a Note has been added at the end to clarify that it's available for all users.

Hope it's clearer now!
Eva

Comment: Well, not quite, unfortunately. The following statement has been added to the connector description: "This connector is preinstalled in Anypoint Studio and available for all users." Actually, it raises more questions. What does the verb "available" means in regards to the possible commercial use of the connector on a production environment? The interpretation could vary. The real issue is  the  "Connector Categories" table which still says "you must have an active CloudHub Select plan or an Enterprise subscription with an entitlement for the specific connector you wish to use.".

Comment: Yes, I understand and that's the concern that I raised. I will raise this new concern, but unfortunately that's all I can do. I will keep you updated.

Comment: Just to keep you posted, I sent the concern about the Connector's Category and it's currently under review. I'll be notified of the outcome so I'll let you know. 
You can contact a Mulesoft representative if you want to make sure you can use it in the meantime (as I'm sure you can), despite the documentation's ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has now been updated to clarify the scope of the Select Category for this case, please see the new [definition](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/anypoint-connectors#connector-categories):

"MuleSoft maintains Select Connectors. Connectors included in the open source Mule distribution can be used by everyone, although support is only included in an Anypoint Platform subscription. For all other Select Connectors, you must have an active Anypoint Platform subscription to use them and access support."

Hope it's clear now,
Eva

Comment: Ok, then you MuleSoft has two different definitions. First, for the Community connectors it's written like this:

Comment: First, for the Community connectors it's written like this:"You do not need any special account or license to use a Community connector." For the Select it's like this "..can be used by everyone". On what conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by free ? It's part of the CE edition - for specific questions on licensing for your specific scenario I would recommend you contact Mulesoft directly.

Comment: Why would I need contacting MuleSoft to answer this? Is MueSoft making the decision on the case to case basis i.e. similar to their price model? "Free" means CPAL (or any other free license)  on the code and the binaries.

Comment: So you don't stumble on any surprises later on.

Comment: Hmm, I think it would be more reasonable to clearly state the connector license in advance, wouldn't it?

Answer (score -1):

It is free. Just try to setup a standalone Mule environment and deploy a application with the HTTP connector in it. No problems at all.

Comment: Actually, this proves nothing. You can get EE runtime running with no issue. Does it mean that it's free? I doubt that.

Comment: The EE is free for 30 days, then it stops working.
When you install a Select connector in AnypointStudio (additional to the existing ones) and drag it into a CE project, you get the error message "EE license needed". So my understanding - as some have stated above - is: All select connectors part of CE are free. Additional ones not.